# Select all items that don't belong to a certain user but others in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Here is my table:

[image]

I want to select all HealthInsurancePlanIDs that don't belong to a CompanyID but others.

For CompanyID = 2:

1. HealthInsurancePlanID 2 belongs to CompanyID 2 & others, so skip this.
2. HealthInsurancePlanID 4 belongs to CompanyID 2, so skip this.
3. HealthInsurancePlanID 5 is not belong to CompanyID 2, but others(3) so, I want to select this.

Finally, it will return the 5 only as HealthInsurancePlanID.

**I want to do this by one single linq.**

Here is my try - HealthInsuranceBrokerPlan is the Entity.

```
context.HealthInsuranceBrokerPlan
       .Where(p => p.CompanyID != 144)
       //.Where(p => p.CompanyID != companyId)
       .GroupBy(p => p.HealthInsurancePlanID)
       .Select(p => p.Key)
       .ToList();
```

But it returns HealthInsurancePlanID that also belong to the provided CompanyID.

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at doing this yourself?

Comment: have you tried to do this with sql?if yes can you share it.

Comment: Assuming you have foreign keys set correctly, and you are autogenerating dbContext and entity classes, this will do the job: `context.HealthInsurancePlans.Where(x=>x.HealthInsuranceBrokerPlans.All(b=>b.CompanyId !=2 )).ToList()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following :

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("HealthInsurancePlanID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("CompanyID", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 2 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 3 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 4 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 4, 2 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 5, 3 });

            var results = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(x => x.Field<int>("HealthInsurancePlanID"))
                .Where(x => !x.Any(y => y.Field<int>("CompanyID") == 2))
                .ToList();
```